# Plymouth doesnt work correctly

Tags: plymouth

When i boot my pc boot normaly exept for that the Ubuntu logo isnt showing up ,with its dots below it.

reinstaling plymouth does not work.

grub contains "quiet splash"

Answer (score 0):

1. Run this in a terminal

   > sudo apt-get install plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
2. #### if the following command returns `There is only one alternative..` just skip it!

   `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`
   then type the selection number of `/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth`
3. Finaly, apply changes by typing :

   > sudo update-initramfs -u

Comment: what do you mean with selection number?

Comment: after typing `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` you will be asked to chose a theme for plymouth by typing the selection number according to the theme you want to chose.

Comment: and if Step 2 returns something like this `There is only one alternative..` just skip it!

Comment: Tried it but the logo is still missing.

Comment: I guess we'll have to wait for the pros